# Calculate age based on birthdate returns NaN

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

In my code I am trying to get age of the person! The problem is it giving me result as "NaN". Where am I going wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var birthDate = new Date(1994, 04, 30);
  var mdate = birthDate.toString();
  var yearThen = parseInt(mdate.substring(0, 4), 10);
  var monthThen = parseInt(mdate.substring(5, 7), 10);
  var dayThen = parseInt(mdate.substring(8, 10), 10);

  var today = new Date();
  var birthday = new Date(yearThen, monthThen - 1, dayThen);
  var differenceInMilisecond = today.valueOf() - birthday.valueOf();
  var year_age = Math.floor(differenceInMilisecond / 31536000000);

  document.getElementById("currentAge").innerHTML = year_age + " Years Old";

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Age Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    <cenrter>Age Calculator</cenrter>
  </h1>

  Age:
  <div id="currentAge"></div>

  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you debugged your intermediate values to see where it is going wrong?

Comment: `var yearThen = parseInt(mdate.substring(0,4), 10);` console.log this variable and see

Comment: Why are you converting the date to a string and using `substr()` instead of using functions like `getYear()`, `getMonth()`, etc.?

Comment: Your code seems to expect `mdate` to be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Do `console.log(mdate)` and see what it actually looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would check your value printing in console of `mdate, yearThen, monthThen` etc, you would see where the error is.
Instead, you can use default method to get those values like this:

```
    var birthDate = new Date(1994, 04, 30);
      var yearThen =birthDate.getFullYear();
      var monthThen = birthDate.getMonth();
      var dayThen = birthDate.getDate();

      var today = new Date();
      var birthday = new Date(yearThen, monthThen - 1, dayThen);
      var differenceInMilisecond = today.valueOf() - birthday.valueOf();
      var year_age = Math.floor(differenceInMilisecond / 31536000000);

  document.getElementById("currentAge").innerHTML = year_age + " Years Old";
```

check the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyqgdc81/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how the exact function should be.
enjoy coding.
Your year and month was coming as NaN. The reason is substring was incorrect at first place. It was giving character and you were converting letters into integer which is not possible.

This is how your date looks like: Mon May 30 1994 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var birthDate = new Date(1994, 04, 30);
    var mdate = birthDate.toString();
    var yearThen = parseInt(mdate.substring(10, 15), 10);
    var mon = new Date(Date.parse(" May, 1, 2012")).getMonth() + 1;
    var monthThen = new Date(Date.parse(mdate.substring(3, 7) + ", 1, 2012")).getMonth() + 1;
    var dayThen = parseInt(mdate.substring(8, 10), 10);
    var today = new Date();
    var birthday = new Date(yearThen, monthThen - 1, dayThen);
    var differenceInMilisecond = today.valueOf() - birthday.valueOf();
    var year_age = Math.floor(differenceInMilisecond / 31536000000);
    document.getElementById("currentAge").innerHTML = year_age + " Years Old";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well you don't need to get day,month,year just difference between  date divided by `(365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

```js
var birthDate  = new Date(1994, 04, 30);
  var today = new Date();
  var year_age = Math.floor((today-birthDate)/ 31536000000);
$("#currentAge").html(year_age + " Years Old")
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Age Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    <cenrter>Age Calculator</cenrter>
  </h1>

  Age:
  <div id="currentAge"></div>

  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change value of parameters according to The following code:

```
var mdate = birthDate; 
var yearThen = mdate.getFullYear(); 
var monthThen = mdate.getMonth(); 
var dayThen = mdate.getDate();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can calculate age with this

```
var year_age = Math.floor(today -birthDate / 31536000000);
```

you don't need month, day ....
if you need  month and day use getYear(), getMonth() ,getFullYear() function